# How to report current title to Google Analytics from angular?

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular-router

I have successfully reported the URL of the current page to Google Analytics, but it is reporting the previous page's title.

I have looked at several tutorials, and none of them discuss the page title.

Here is the code in my `app.component.ts` file that I am using:

```js
constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            // FIXME need to make this track the correct current title.
            gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', {
                page_path: event.urlAfterRedirects
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I would expect it to report the title that I set after the constructor for the page has run, but it seems to be sending the previous one. My title is generated based on data from a subscription if that provides any useful context.

Comment: By default the page title does not change. In what case do you set your page title ?

Comment: @NoémiSalaün I change the title in my pages that I route to with `this.setTitle(this.groupName + ' - Home');` in the constructor. Should I do it in some other way?

Comment: Would it be advised to push the `gtag()` after I set the title on each page?

Comment: Hum it works in my project. I listen to the router like you show in your question and I set the title in the constructor of my page. If I `console.log` in both place, I see the setTitle before the navigationEnd and the navigationEnd get the new title. Your page component is the component directly created by the routing ?

Comment: I figured it out. The title was being set based on a call to a rest api and because it is an async call it was not able to set the new title until that had completed. I was able to fix it by sending the page view in the callback to that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the same logic in ngOninit, as constructor is not a place to set or get properties.

```
 export class App implements OnInit{ 
      constructor(){
         //called first time before the ngOnInit()
       }

   ngOnInit(){
       //called after the constructor and called  after the first ngOnChanges() 
    }
 }
```